# Wrong colors on pre-lollipop devices with AppCompatTheme

Tags: android, colors, styles, themes, android-appcompat

I have this in my style.xml file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
    <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginScreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/login_background_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginEditTextTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/login_edit_text_hint_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/login_edit_text_accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/login_edit_text_accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/login_edit_text_hint_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginErrorFloatingLabelTheme" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/login_error_floating_label_color</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/home_primary_color</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginWaitingProgressBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange_light</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

On devices with Lollipop and upper everything is alright, but on pre-lollipop there are wrong colors. It's look like theme is not applied to the devices with pre-lollipop android version. After googling I found that people are adviced to remove 'android:' prefix before every item in AppCompat theme but it doesn't work for me coz android studio doesn't see items after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I didn't extend AppCompatActivity. When I changed it everything became okay.

Answer (score -1):

colorPrimary , colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent items are available on only API 21+.If you want to apply them on pre lollipop devices you must move your current styles.xml file to values-v21 and create a new styles.xml on values folder and use the correct item for pre lollipop.

Check out android developers for more https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html